# Is there any support for using Facebook SDK in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, dart-packages

I would like to add the Facebook app-events to my Flutter project : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/ios

It relies on the Facebook SDK. However, it seems that there is no available plugin for the Facebook SDK integration in Flutter.

May I know should Flutter users implement their plugin to use the Facebook features?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login   and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth

Comment: Hi Andrey, many thanks for the references. I've used these plugins as well in my projects. They work fine. However, the facebook product app-events requires the information which cannot be provided in flutter app.(e.g. application context). I have no way to migrate this product from my original Android application to the new Flutter application.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I didn't use FB in flutter yet. I think, in this case only way is to add FB SDK for android and work through FlutterActivity

Comment: Hi Andrey and all, thanks for replying. I've prepared a flutter plugin which integrates the FB SDK. However, I find that this Facebook product(app-events) supports only to track the events in native Android/iOS structure(e.g. use android activities as input for the event logging). In my flutter project, most of my widgets are under lib folder. there is no android activities. I think I am not able to proceed even I can call the APIs in Facebook SDK.

Comment: Don't you have "android" and "ios" folder on the same level as "lib"?

Comment: @h19881103 Did you figure out how to do this? I want to be able to use FaceBook app events (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events) in my flutter app, without using FaceBook login, in order to track the effects of marketing campaigns. Any updates on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to get the app installs from facebook ads campaign? I am not able to get any app engagement data

Comment: Why don't you try this pub instead of writing native code: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_sdk/example

Comment: @AmitKabra Did you get any change to get analytics of app installation from Facebook ads Campaign? We're looking into same direction for one of our app.

Answer (score 21):

At the time of answering this, there is currently no official plugin or package from the Facebook team.

But I had the same needs as you, so I wrote and published a plugin: [facebook_app_events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events)

It supports [codeless app events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/codeless-app-events/) as well as implements most of the App Events SDK.

Hope that answers your question and needs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It's really useful and i would say basic for any app to be marketed on FB to include fb events

Comment: @Dennis Alund, I've created my app this week on facebook and I'm not getting analytics data. Do you think it has to do with the "pause of individual verification"? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/03/24/pausing-individual-verification/

Comment: Hm, not sure how the facebook analytics work. But for Firebase it can take up to 24hrs before we see the data after adding SDK.

Comment: @DennisAlund how have you done it? It doesn't work for me, I can see my phone but not clicking in any button to link an event

Comment: Did you manage to get it work Ricardo? Happy to get a detailed bug report if you have are experiencing any issues or if you think that the documentation could be improved.

Comment: Does this package support automatic logging for the 'app install' kind of events?

Comment: Yes, I actually think you get the app install events automatically if you're using any part of the Facebook SDK. But definitely, for this plugin you do get it.

Comment: @DennisAlund unfortunately not, it doesn't track the standard events

Comment: Hi, am always getting 
"Error registering plugin facebook_app_events, id.oddbit.flutter.facebook_app_events.FacebookAppEventsPlugin
The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first."
this error wher using the library

Comment: Hi there, @arjunkn sounds like a question to be opened by itself. Please post a question with full code context and as much information as possible and I'll try to help.

Comment: @DennisAlund My mistake it's ok now, Good work.

Comment: Happy you got it working! If you found something missing in the setup instructions, feel free to start a discussion on the repo:https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/discussions